# How to match all symbols around the text

Tags: php

```
$text = '2434__(this is something)-__2345';

 preg_match('/[\p{Latin}]+/u', text, $matches);
```

here I get a match only of text, but how can I match all the symbls in the text thats exists or if not exists?

Comment: which part of the text do you want match?

Comment: I want to match all the symbols that may appear around the text, around the letters, including braces, slashed and others symbols

Comment: I have this text "some text" - I match it, but if there are other symbols I miss them, so I want to match them too

Comment: What you mean *around* ? The prefix and sufix or just before and after the text?

Comment: before and after the text, "begin text some spaces end text", all that is before and after I want to match

Comment: what's a symbol? is a number a symbol? is underscore? whitespace? etc...

Comment: all the symbols, excluding the text itself

Comment: voted to close. you're clearly unable to describe what you want.

Comment: Do you want "2434__()-__2345" as result in this example?

Comment: i want to get the text itself plus all the symbols before and after the text, not only the text itself

Comment: Check my edited answer, that should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

This will match all the symbols:

```
$match = $text
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope that understood what you want right..

```
preg_match('/^([^\p{Latin}]+)([\p{Latin}\s]*)([^\p{Latin}]+)$/u', $text, $matches);

print_r($matches);
```